# SparkSQL: Use custom column in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.3.0 .In my application , I have created a dataframe with following `columns (col1, col2, col3,col4)`

I have to derive a custom column(a new column) in the dataframe.
So my SQL query looks like

```
SELECT (col1 + col1/10) as col1 , col2, col3 , col4 FROM table GROUP BY col1 , col2
```

My requirement in to group by new custom column and not the old col1. But the above query doesnt work properly. It still group by old col1. I know I have given the same name to new custom column as old column name. Even if try to give new name to custom column like:

```
SELECT (col1 + col1/10) as new_col1 , col2, col3 , col4 FROM table GROUP BY new_col1 , col2
```

It fails with following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'new_col1' given input columns..
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this??
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the remaining part is a valid aggregation you can either use subquery:

```
SELECT  new_col1 AS col1, sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col4)
FROM (
    SELECT *, col1 + col1 / 10 AS new_col1 FROM table
) AS tmp GROUP BY new_col1, col2
```

or repeat the formula in the group by clause.

```
SELECT (col1 + col1/10) as col1 , sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col4)
FROM table
GROUP BY (col1 + col1 / 10), col2
```

Note that the first option requires unambiguous alias for the computed column.